# Interface Builder Auto Add UIImageView to my View

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, interface-builder

I create Interface builder tree like this

```
myScrollview
    UIView
```

when i run it appear that the scroll view have 3 subviews like this

```
myScrollview
   UIView
   UIImageView
   UIImageView
```

this result is tested by this code (with breakpoint and watch panel) 
which code is added before super viewDidLoad

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < myScrollview.subviews.count ; i++){  
    id temp = [myScrollview.subviews objectAtIndex:i];  
}
```

the error appear after I delete some property and I already check interface builder there has no warning relate to this deletion left

What should I do to get more clue about this bug?

---

> SOLVED

I move 3rd scrollview to behind. This view is loaded with loadNib
and I guess I fail to set it hidden(already set it but it is not disappear). 
Don't know where should I set ThridScrollView.hidden = TRUE. ~__~'

Comment: Did you look at the object list in IB (left menu) to make sure it is not still there but maybe was hidden behind the scrollview for example?

Comment: Yes I look in IB left menu and see only one UIView inside. and nothing behind myScrollView.

Comment: Did you try to do a project clean command - that can happen with changes in IB.

Comment: already clean it once.

Comment: If these properties were created in code and then linked to IB objects and then deleted, we will have to see the code to see if there are any remnants? Please post the class.m/.h where these properties were listed?

Comment: Actually I have 3 scrollview. I remove 3rd scrollview to change it to normal view. The 3rd one work same as before but the 1st and 2nd is affected by have the white black imageview cover the others views inside.

Answer (score 0):

That code is wrong. You are looking for objects inside myScrollview and not myScrollview.subviews

It should be:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < myScrollview.subviews.count ; i++){  
    id temp = [myScrollview.subviews objectAtIndex:i];  
}
```

Comment: Regardless of this, you'll still see the image views, but it's perfectly normal - it's undocumented scroll view behaviour.

Comment: sorry, my post is not complete. fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal, and I can reproduce it myself in IB. A `UIScrollView` contains many subviews that you don't have access to. This includes some `UIImageViews`, which are used to show the 'gradients' that appear when you bounce/scroll a `UIScrollView` past its edge.

What you are seeing are the 'private' views that Apple use themselves in the scroll view implementation. You should ignore them, and bear in mind that for most of Apple's provided view classes (scroll views, table views, collection views, etc) there are additional subviews that are undocumented and being used by Apple internally. As a general rule, you should bear in mind that `subviews` can be deceptive as there is stuff going on in `UIView` subclasses you are not normally aware of.

If you are having problems that you think might involve these private image views then let us know - perhaps provide more detail about what exactly the problem is? Screenshots could be very useful.

Comment: thanks for this info , I try to test it on other scrollview and it appear to have those imageviews too.
So the problem is why this case it automatically come to front?

Comment: Is there other code going on in your project? Are you maybe manually moving subviews up/down the hierarchy? Since these imageviews are normal it sounds as if perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I have read frame size , set hidden , backgroundColor , change frame height , change contentsize , dis/enable userInteraction that's all.